# Need to block just one MAC address on my D-Link DIR-612 but can't find the setting

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, troubleshooting, acl

My parents have a wireless router (D-Link DIR-612) that is provided for by a local telecommunications company. Recently I've detected a phone's MAC address that doesn't belong to any of our devices who leeches off our WiFi. After fiddling around with the settings I found that the DIR-612 has a wireless access control list which allows listed addresses to connect to the router. It would've been all fine if only the router would accept more than 20 addresses [[img]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyS9h.jpg). We run a smart home setup so access to the router is compulsory (and that doesn't include each family members' devices). I couldn't figure out how to do the inverse, so I looked it up on the net and I read that it was under Advanced -> Network Filter -> Turn Mac filtering ON  and Deny Computer listed to access the network [[img]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDVlU.jpg). However, there was no such menu in my settings [[img]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aeacs.jpg). Is there any other way to block access for a single device?

Comment: Does the router provide DHCP services? If so, you can deny that mac address from getting an IP address in DHCP. You could also create a reservation for that MAC and give it an address that doesn't work on your network. But overall, if he is connecting to a wireless network, why not change the password?

Comment: @Larryc [they do](https://www.dlink.co.id/how-do-i-enable-the-dynamic-dns-feature-on-my-dir-612-router/), but from what I see in the manual there doesn't seem to be an option to deny or reserve a MAC address. I'm really baffled by D-Link, it seems like it has far less configs than what I expect from a standard router. For starters, they don't seem to even accept command-line ACL, which would've solved this problem quickly. I was planning to change passwords as a last resort. Too lazy to have to reconnect all those smart devices with the new password.

Answer (score 0):

1. log in to your modems website.
2. select ADVANCED
3. select PARENTAL CONTROL then MAC BLOCK
   Then just fill everything and that should be it :)

Best Regards!

Comment: Sorry, there are no parental control settings on my router web interface. Please check the third image link